# Overriding Product model doesn't work

Tags: override-model, magento-1.9.3.8

I need to add a new method to the Product model, those are the files I created:

*app/etc/modules/Overrides_All.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Overrides_Customs>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Overrides_Customs>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Overrides/Customs/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Overrides_Customs>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Overrides_Customs>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>

            <customs>
                <class>Overrides_Customs_Model</class>
            </customs>

            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Overrides_Customs_Model_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Overrides/Customs/Model/Product.php*

```
<?php
include('Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php');

class Overrides_Customs_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product {
    public function isNewProduct() {
        $newFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getID())->getNewsFromDate();
        $newToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getID())->getNewsToDate();
        $now = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
        if(($newFromDate < $now && $newFromDate != NULL) && ($newToDate > $now || $newToDate == "")){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Everything looks good, but my custom model is not loaded. Where is the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't include original in your class... but I am not sure that could cause the problem. XML files look fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the module from Overrides_All.xml to Overrides_Customs.xml

Use the below code in your model:

```
<?php

class Overrides_Customs_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product {
    public function isNewProduct() {
        $newFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getID())->getNewsFromDate();
        $newToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getID())->getNewsToDate();
        $now = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
        if(($newFromDate < $now && $newFromDate != NULL) && ($newToDate > $now || $newToDate == "")){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

No need to add the include.

Comment: I renamed the file, but the Product model loaded is still "Mage_Catalog_Model_Product". I see the Module as active in the admin interface, so I can't figure out what problem is there. My custom module is simply not loaded.

Comment: Did you flush cache?

Comment: Yes. I installed another module that shows overridden modules, and indeed I see the Product model is not overridden. I tried calling the method anyway, I get unknown method error.

Comment: Please check this blog they are also doing the same so way is correct.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231213/rewriting-magento-core-product-model-using-module Something is wrong from your end. Please check the files and class names thoroughly.

Comment: After trying again with this solution, not sure why, it worked. Probably I mispelled something and couldn't spot it. Thank you